# Why did Trinity intentionally bump into Lundy?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, dexter

In S4E04 of *Dexter* when Lundy is retired and back in Miami chasing Trinity, why did Trinity decide to intentionally bump into Lindy and pretend to drop his keys for Lundy to then return? Just a moment prior when Trinity came out of the building and noticed Lundy, Trinity quickly hid behind the pillar and was dramatically going on about being found so it doesn't really make sense for him to think directly confronting Lundy is the best thing to do.

Also, after their exchange Lundy *did* end up getting suspicious of Trinity, so the whole thing doesn't seem to play to Trinity's advantage. So why would Trinity expose himself like that on purpose.. what was he trying to accomplish?

[image]

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Dexter/comments/4su61j/spoilers_what_was_the_point_of_trinity_s04e04/ and https://www.reddit.com/r/Dexter/comments/a51u7a/spoiler_in_season_4_why_does_trinity_purposefully/ and https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/225-television-broadcast-tv/63964702